# Android firefox version 25 and beyond Can't redirect anywhere?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, firefox, deep-linking

Custom URL redirection is not working in android firefox latest version 25 and beyond.

If the device has an Facebook app installed, goes to app Url. If not, goes to website Url.

Now it can't redirect anywhere in Android latest firefox browser.

It worked with firefox older version, but it doesn't on the latest version 25 and beyond.

Appreciate your inputs on how to resolve this???

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gsk/f792D/

```
if (Android) 
{            
    // this is a mobile app url
    window.location.href = "fb://";         
    var startTime = new Date();         
    setTimeout(function () 
    {
        // Wait for 500msec             
        if (new Date() - startTime < 700) 
        {                       
            // If we are unable to re-direct to mobile application go to website instead
            if (window.location.href != "http://facebook.com") 
            {                            
                window.location.href = "http://facebook.com";
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            goBack();
        }
    }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine in firefox 28 in my android mobile. it opens my fb app. 
please reinstall firefox and check again.